Renaming SSIS packages and deploying issue
I had an SSIS package that was deployed to the SSIS catalog called package.dtsx. I renamed this package (In SSIS Data Tools by right clicking on the package and selecting rename) to Client1.dtsx and then deployed it to the catalog.
So at this point I had Client1.dtsx AND package.dtsx in the catalog which technically is a duplicate (just different names). So I deleted the package.dtsx by using the below code in SQL:
BEGIN TRAN
DELETE [pkg]
FROM
[SSISDB].[internal].[projects] AS [proj] WITH (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN
[SSISDB].[internal].[packages] AS [pkg] WITH (NOLOCK) ON
[pkg].[project_id] = [proj].[project_id]
WHERE
[proj].[name] = 'Company'
AND [pkg].[name] in ('Package.dtsx') 
 COMMIT

At this point I only have Client1.dtsx in the catalog which is exactly what I want.
The problem I'm facing now is that every time I make a change in the package on data tools and redeploy the package to the SQL catalog it deploys Client1.dtsx but ALSO package.dtsx.
It's almost like it's still saving the old package somewhere.
In my windows directory, where the dtsx packages are stored, I only have Client1.dtsx and also only Client1.dtsx exists in data tools in the list of packages within my project.
my structure in data tools is like so:
Solution --> Project --> One dtsx package for each client that we have ie Client1.dtsx, Client2.dtsx etc.
So everytime I make a change to a package, I just redeploy the package itself and this works fine, unless I rename the package from data tools as mentioned above
what am I doing wrong?

This sounds like you "played" with the data in the SSISDB database, rather than using the GUI and VS to correct the changes, and have introduced your own "features"; you should have renamed the package in the project and redeployed the project. You will very likely be better off redeploying the project to SSISDB with the intention of refreshing the full state of play, and hoping your manual changes to the database don't have adverse effects on said deployment.

I did rename the package in the project though (on VS). The only thing I did on the SSISDB is delete the package.dtsx.
The reason I didn't redeploy the whole project is because I have 1 project with multiple packages (representing different clients) and only made a change to the one package/client. Is it still best practice though to redeploy the entire project even though only one package was changed? excuse my ignorance, I'm fairly new to SSIS

Adding/removing packages to a project affects the project (file). You can deploy new packages without redeploying the project, but if you have any project level changes, they won't deploy (such as environment configurations for the package). Removing a package can only be deployed via project deployment; as there's no "undeploy" feature.

So does that mean if I want to rename a package, I should redeploy the whole project after renaming the package in VS? which will "remove" the package with the old name. already within the catalog....if yes, do you think this will fix my issue where the old package keeps showing up after deploying the renamed package?

As i mentioned in my initial comment: "You will very likely be better off redeploying the project to SSISDB with the intention of refreshing the full state of play, and hoping your manual changes to the database don't have adverse effects on said deployment."

adding to what @ThomA said, you should consider redesigning your ssis solution. perhaps break down the solution to different project based on clients or whaever suits your usecase. This way, you wont be in dilemma of whether you would deploy the whole content of your solution/project despite changes on only one client. And please dont modify records in SSISDB manually. You may be opening pandora's box with that.
